# Getting the captions from a YouTube video

Tags: youtube

If you inspect a YouTube video with cc turned on, you can see

```
document.getElementsByClassName('captions-text')
```

is being populated dynamically.

Q: How can I get the transcript of a closed-caption YouTube video?
I've tried embedding it in an iFrame, but then for some reason I can't find it in the dom any longer.

I wonder if I can use object.observe to get the text as it's streaming, or what would be best would be to simply get it along with their time codes in one large string or object.

Comment: Did you check their API? https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Retrieve_Caption_Track

Comment: I don't understand it.  Can you put together an example on jsbin using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nMD6sjAe8I&list=FLID2RpRJlvYgTnw5SjdzItA&index=6?